# RecyclerView crushes when using notifyDataSetChanged()

Tags: java, kotlin, listview, android-recyclerview, android-developer-api

I created this app to show two recycler views, one containing paired devices and the other containing nearby available devices. The app works as intended until the ACTION_FOUND broadcast receiver is called, when a new device is added to the list, the app suddenly crashes. Why does this happen?

Broadcast receiver code:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Broadcast", "Broadcast called");
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                final String deviceName = device.getName();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (deviceName != null) {
                            availableDevices.add(deviceName);
                            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    };
```

This is my whole code:

```
package com.example.wheelchairapp;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.graphics.PaintKt;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.health.PackageHealthStats;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Set;

import android.Manifest;

public class DevicesList extends AppCompatActivity {
    ActionBar actionBar;
    BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    ArrayList<String> availableDevices;
    RecyclerView.Adapter adapter2;
    private static final int REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION = 1001;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices_list);
        actionBarSet();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        availableDevices = new ArrayList<String>();
        recycler1ViewSettings(getPairedDevices());
        recycler2ViewSettings();
        registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Not Discovering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Discovering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        else {
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_BLUETOOTH_PERMISSION);
            bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
            if (!bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()){
                Toast.makeText(this, "isn't Discovering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else if(bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Discovery started from else", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        unregisterReceiver(receiver);
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Log.d("Broadcast", "Broadcast called");
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                final String deviceName = device.getName();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (deviceName != null) {
                            availableDevices.add(deviceName);
                            adapter2.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }
                });

            }
        }
    };

    private String[] getPairedDevices() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            Set<BluetoothDevice> bt = bluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();
            String[] pairedDevices = new String[bt.size()];
            int i = 0;
            for(BluetoothDevice d : bt){
                pairedDevices[i] = d.getName();
                i++;
            }
            return pairedDevices;
        }
        else{
            return new String[0];
        }
    }
    private void recycler1ViewSettings(String[] pairedDevices){
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerList1);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        RecyclerView.Adapter adapter = new CustomAdapter (pairedDevices, DevicesList.this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    private void recycler2ViewSettings(){
        RecyclerView recyclerView2 = findViewById(R.id.recyclerList2);
        recyclerView2.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView2.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter2 = new CustomAdapter2(availableDevices, this);
        recyclerView2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }
    private void actionBarSet(){
        actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        assert actionBar != null;
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.baseline_arrow_back_24);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hello.  I think you mean crashes.  Can you post the crash and a bit more of your code that shows how adapter2 is initialized?

Comment: Thanks.  What is the exception being thrown when you look in logcat?  I suspect a NullPointerException?  You might consider creating an intent, filling it with the device data, and then starting your activity with the intent.  Then in your activity you'll need to pull the data out of the intent in order to use it.